# Getting "TypeError" when executing code with Blank or Null key in python 3 whereas same code works fine with python2

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, null, typeerror

**What I am trying to do:**
I have a dictionary in python and I am simply trying to assign a blank key to one of the keys of this dictionary. My code works fine with python2 but same code is throwing error with python3

**Example to explain what I am trying to achieve:**
In simple terms, here's what I am trying to achieve.
Say I have a dictionary with following data:

```
key1 = value1
key2 = value2
key3 = value3
```

Now how I want my dictionary to look like is:

```
     = value1
key2 = value2
key3 = value3
```

where key1 is blank and contain no values or spaces, just a blank key.

**What I tried:**
I have a dictionary whose keys have been extracted out in an array named **key_list**, whose length is variable (depending upon length of my dictionary) and I am trying to assign a blank value to one of the items of this array which will then be assigned back as keys to the dictionary. Here's how I am making a key blank:

```
key_list[i] = "" , where i is the ith key which I am trying to make blank
```

Now, the issue is that when I run this code using python 2, it works as desired and the corresponding **i**th key is set to blank and it works perfectly but if I execute the same code with python3, it throws following error:

```
 key_list[i] = ""
TypeError: 'dict_keys' object does not support item assignment
```

Can someone please help me understand what changes between python 2 & 3 due to which I am getting this error because I am not changing anything in code. All I am changing is just my execution command and running same code with python2 & python3 and that's all where I see this error popping up for python3 ?

I even tried following statement:

```
list(keys_list)[i] = ""
```

but still I see the value being passed as it is and the key is still not made blank. Like in above example, I am still getting:

```
key1 = value1
```

I have checked all other values like value of i etc and everything else has correct value but still, only with python3, I see original key being passed, instead of a null key. Whereas, for same code, with python2, I am getting desired result of:

```
= value1
```

Your help  is much appreciated!
Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

It's because the behaviour of `dict.keys` changed between Python 2 and Python 3.

The [doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.keys) of Python 2 states:

> keys()
> return a copy of the dictionary’s list of keys.

Whereas the [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.keys) of Python 3 states:

> keys()
> Return a new view of the dictionary’s keys.

A view may not be directly updated, but reflect the updates of the dict.

If you write this:

```
d = {"key1": "value1", "key2": "value2", "key3": "value3"}
print(d.keys())
```

Python2 will print:

```
['key3', 'key2', 'key1'] # this is a list
```

Whereas Python 3 will print:

```
dict_keys(['key1', 'key2', 'key3']) # this is a view
```

If you want a list (not an "array") in Python 3, just create the list from the view:

```
print(list(d.keys()))
```

Python 2 & 3:

```
['key3', 'key2', 'key1']
```

---

**About `list(keys_list)[i] = ""`**

This does not work because you: 1. create a list that is a copy of the keys; 2. assign a empty string to the i-th element of this list; 3. ...drop the list!

You have to make a copy of the keys into a list **and keep a reference on this copy**:

```
>>> d = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
>>> L = list(d.keys())
>>> L 
['a', 'b']
```

And then assign something to this copy, using the reference:

```
>>> L[0] = 'c'
>>> L
['c', 'b']
```

Finally, use this copy as intended.

Comment: Thank you for responding to my query. But the issue is that I have already tried doing that as well and surprisingly that also doesn't work for Python 3.

If you see in my question above, I have mentioned this as well:

I even tried following statement:

list(keys_list)[i] = ""

but still I see the value being passed as it is and the key is still not made blank.

Comment: I'll definitely try this one.  Thank you for helping :)